# Numba crashes Python with parallel=True flag set

Tags: python, multithreading, numba

I'm trying to speed up some calculations using the Numba. The call of the `nnleapfrog_integrate` function lead to segmentation fault and crash of the Python process. The function works fine if the `parallel=True` flag is removed from its jit decorator. But then it runs in single thread. I want this fuction to run as fast as possible, thus I want it to run in multi threads to utilize all the CPU cores.

```python
from numba import jit, prange
import numpy as np

@jit('Tuple((f8[:,:,::1],f8[:,:,::1]))(f8[:,::1], f8[:,::1], f8[::1], i8, i8, i8, f8, f8)', nopython=True,  parallel=True)
def nnleapfrog_integrate(pos, vel, mass, i_steps, r_steps, dt, G, softening):
    N = pos.shape[0]
    pos_data = np.zeros((int(np.ceil(i_steps/r_steps)), N, 3))
    vel_data = np.zeros((int(np.ceil(i_steps/r_steps)), N, 3))
    data_idx = 0
    acc = np.zeros((N,3))
    for s in range(i_steps):
        vel += acc * dt/2.0
        pos += vel * dt
        for i in prange(N):
            acc[i,0] =  0
            acc[i,1] =  0
            acc[i,2] =  0
            for j in range(N):
                dx = pos[j,0] - pos[i,0]
                dy = pos[j,1] - pos[i,1]
                dz = pos[j,2] - pos[i,2]
                inv_r3 = (dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2 + softening**2)**(-1.5)
                acc[i,0] +=  G * (dx * inv_r3) * mass[j]
                acc[i,1] +=  G * (dy * inv_r3) * mass[j]
                acc[i,2] +=  G * (dz * inv_r3) * mass[j]
        vel += acc * dt/2.0
        if s % r_steps == 0:
            pos_data[data_idx] = pos
            vel_data[data_idx] = vel
            data_idx += 1
    return pos_data, vel_data

N = 10
dt = 60
pos = np.random.rand(N, 3)
vel = np.random.rand(N, 3)
m = np.random.rand(N)
softening = 1e3
G = 6.67430e-11
t_max = 3600*24*30
i_steps = int(t_max/dt)
r_steps = int(3600*24/dt)
r_i, v_i = nnleapfrog_integrate(pos, vel, m, i_steps, r_steps, dt, G, softening)
```

## What I have already tried

Because only the `for i in prange(N):` loop is suitable for parallelization, so I have separated it to the separate function `getAcc` which is works fine with the `parallel=True` flag and utilizes all the CPU cores.

```python
from numba import jit, prange
import numpy as np

@jit('f8[:, ::1](f8[:, ::1], f8[::1], f8, f8)', nopython=True, parallel=True)
def getAcc( pos, mass, G, softening ):
    N = pos.shape[0]
    a = np.zeros((N,3))
    for i in prange(N):
        for j in range(N):
            dx = pos[j,0] - pos[i,0]
            dy = pos[j,1] - pos[i,1]
            dz = pos[j,2] - pos[i,2]
            inv_r3 = (dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2 + softening**2)**(-1.5)
            a[i,0] +=  G * (dx * inv_r3) * mass[j]
            a[i,1] +=  G * (dy * inv_r3) * mass[j]
            a[i,2] +=  G * (dz * inv_r3) * mass[j]
    return a

@jit('Tuple((f8[:,:,::1],f8[:,:,::1]))(f8[:,::1], f8[:,::1], f8[::1], i8, i8, i8, f8, f8)', nopython=True)
def nleapfrog_integrate(pos, vel, mass, i_steps, r_steps, dt, G, softening):
    N = pos.shape[0]
    pos_data = np.zeros((int(np.ceil(i_steps/r_steps)), N, 3))
    vel_data = np.zeros((int(np.ceil(i_steps/r_steps)), N, 3))
    data_idx = 0
    acc = getAcc(pos, mass, G, softening)
    for i in range(i_steps):
        vel += acc * dt/2.0
        pos += vel * dt
        acc = getAcc( pos, mass, G, softening )
        vel += acc * dt/2.0
        if i % r_steps == 0:
            pos_data[data_idx] = pos
            vel_data[data_idx] = vel
            data_idx += 1
    return pos_data, vel_data

N = 10
dt = 60
pos = np.random.rand(N, 3)
vel = np.random.rand(N, 3)
m = np.random.rand(N)
softening = 1e3
G = 6.67430e-11
t_max = 3600*24*30
i_steps = int(t_max/dt)
r_steps = int(3600*24/dt)
r_i, v_i = nleapfrog_integrate(pos, vel, m, i_steps, r_steps, dt, G, softening)
```

But it turned out to be more than 3 times slower than the single threaded version of the original  function in which this cycle was inlined.

```python
In [4]: %timeit r_i, v_i = nleapfrog_integrate(pos, vel, m, i_steps, r_steps, dt, G, softening)
8.51 s ± 46.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [5]: %timeit r_i, v_i = nnleapfrog_integrate(pos, vel, m, i_steps, r_steps, dt, G, softening)
2.53 s ± 18.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Therefore for the best performance, I need the original function with the inlined `for i in prange(N):` loop to run in multi threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parallelisation of the i-based loop is not efficient because **creating and synchronizing threads is expensive**. Indeed, this overhead is usually at least dozens of microseconds on PC and often significantly even bigger on computing server (mainly because of the additional cores). The thing is there is `i_steps=43200` iteration so this overhead will result in few seconds. There is **not enough work to use threads efficiently** with `N=10`.

Besides, note that there is a bug in Numba 0.57.0 causing a segmentation fault on this code so I am not sure this is even safe to parallelize it.

Fortunately, the serial code can be optimized:

- `x * y**(-1.5)` is not efficient because Numba use the expensive exponential function `pow` to compute it. You can use `x / (y * sqrt(y))` instead. This is significantly faster because most CPUs have an integrated hardware unit to compute square root and division relatively efficiently.
- The `fastmath` option is not enabled so Numba cannot assume that `x*y` is equal to `y*x` preventing some optimizations. Enabling this flag can be dangerous, but the optimization can be done manually by pre-computing values in the inner loop.

Here is the resulting optimized code:

```py
@jit('Tuple((f8[:,:,::1],f8[:,:,::1]))(f8[:,::1], f8[:,::1], f8[::1], i8, i8, i8, f8, f8)', nopython=True)
def nnleapfrog_integrate(pos, vel, mass, i_steps, r_steps, dt, G, softening):
    N = pos.shape[0]
    pos_data = np.zeros((int(np.ceil(i_steps/r_steps)), N, 3))
    vel_data = np.zeros((int(np.ceil(i_steps/r_steps)), N, 3))
    data_idx = 0
    acc = np.zeros((N,3))
    for s in range(i_steps):
        vel += acc * dt/2.0
        pos += vel * dt
        for i in range(N):
            acc[i,0] = 0.0
            acc[i,1] = 0.0
            acc[i,2] = 0.0
            for j in range(N):
                dx = pos[j,0] - pos[i,0]
                dy = pos[j,1] - pos[i,1]
                dz = pos[j,2] - pos[i,2]
                tmp1 = dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2 + softening**2
                tmp2 = G * mass[j] / (tmp1 * np.sqrt(tmp1))
                acc[i,0] += tmp2 * dx
                acc[i,1] += tmp2 * dy
                acc[i,2] += tmp2 * dz
        vel += acc * dt/2.0
        if s % r_steps == 0:
            pos_data[data_idx] = pos
            vel_data[data_idx] = vel
            data_idx += 1
    return pos_data, vel_data
```

This code is about **5 times faster** on my machine with a i5-9600KF processor. It runs in approximately 31 ms. This means every iteration of the encompassing loop takes only 0.72 µs (far smaller than the overhead of thread creation/synchronization).

Further optimizations include pre-computing `G * mass[j]` and computing the division/sqrt using SIMD instruction. The former is easy to do and the later is a bit tricky, especially in Numba.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your code is about 3 times faster than my on the i5-4200U CPU. Precomputing the `G * mass[j]` gives a performance boost about 0.4% so it doesn't really makes difference. I think it is the limit of performance for this type of computations using Numba, in CPU at least.